# ReadProcessMemory Win32API in Mono / Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mono, readprocessmemory

I've been programming in Windows for a while now, and was talking with a friend today about Ubuntu and I'm now curious as to if this function exists or not. I know it's in win32api as I've used it before, but where will it be on Linux?

Any helpers?

Comment: Memory of process with id XYZ is mapped to a file `/proc/XYZ/mem`. One can read an write it, given sufficient permissions.

Comment: More exactly, [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux).

Answer (score 2):

Nowhere. This function is the part of WinAPI. Linux doesn't implement WinAPI, since Linux is... well, Linux, which is not Windows.

Comment: I know that WinAPI doesn't exist on Linux, obviously, I'm wondering where the function ReadProcessMemory might be found on Linux, or how one might go about calling it...

Comment: @XtrmJosh The `ReadProcessMemory()` function is **not** present in Linux.

Comment: How about a similar function? I've just been told of ptrace(), though I've been given a chunk of C++ code which explains it, and I don't know C++ well enough to make use of it...

Comment: @XtrmJosh See the [first Google hit](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/52375-reading-memory-other-processes.html), it's plain C.